# Camel Salesforce Authentication challenge without WWW-Authenticate header

Tags: java, apache-camel, salesforce

I am trying to push/get values to salesforce using camel with java. When I try to send data I get the following error :

```
HTTP protocol violation: Authentication challenge without WWW-Authenticate header
```

The strange part is that it work like a charm when I subscribe to data with routes /data/AccountChangeEvent

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {

    from("salesforce:/data/AccountChangeEvent?replayId=-2")
            .bean(clientService, "accountChange");

        from("direct:updateSalesforce")
                .to("salesforce:createSObject?sObjectName=Account");
    }
}

public class SalesforcePublisherService {

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;

    public void publishToSalesforce(String endpointUri, Object body) {
        Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
        // [...] Putting some values
        camelContext.createProducerTemplate().requestBody("direct:updateSalesforce", values);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.

First I found out that the error was really different from what was written. In order to investigate on that part I activated Jetty's logs with :

```
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog 
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG
```

Then I reproduce the call on my postman and I got the message from this 401 error. After some investigation the problem was related with how I generated my refresh token:

**I shouldn't have used the scope "refresh_token"** when generating the salesforces token (actually no scope is needed).